# Rotating in the Y direction css

Tags: css

Trying to make a logo rotate in the Y direction as so :

```
@keyframes rotateLogo {
  0% {
    transform: rotateY(0deg)
  }
  // 50% {
  //   transform: rotateY(180deg)
  // }
  100% {
    transform: rotateY(360deg)
  }
}

.splashAnimation{
  animation-name: rotateLogo;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}
```

However it ends up looking like this:

https://giphy.com/gifs/g0gEjkRZ5lLI3mLBDo

Thanks for reading, will post a jsbin but i imagine this is a known issue.

JSBIN: https://jsbin.com/yihoriniso/edit?html,css,output

---

EDIT: This seems to happen as described because of an optical illusion. Is there any way to provide perspective in the rotation so as to provide some cues to the brain to perceive the rotation as unidirectional?

Comment: `It seems to work SOME of the times, others it doesnt` ??

Comment: Please include all relevant code, including HTML as well, and any other CSS rules that might be conflicting with the ones you have at the moment.

Comment: I think you're running into the [spinning dancer illusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinning_Dancer): because you are using a 2D transform and rotating along the y-axis, there is no visual depth cues to which direction it is actually rotating. In other words, **there is nothing inherently broken in your code**, it's just your mind playing tricks on you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a human vision illusion due to the lack of 3D depth, instead of a fault in the code.

Comment: it would be an illusion if the logo was symmetrical. but the logo isnt, see gif.

Comment: It does not have to be: did you even read the wikipedia article I linked? I'll be damned if the spinning dancer is bilaterally symmetrical: which is not. Just like your logo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `perspective` to your logo's parent element in order to get the '3d' feel to it, like so:

```css
body {
  perspective: 800px;
  background-color: #eee;
}

@keyframes rotateLogo {
  0% {
    transform: rotateY(0deg)
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateY(360deg)
  }
}

.splashAnimation{
  animation-name: rotateLogo;
  animation-duration: 3s;

  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  /* animation-timing-function: linear; */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>it works here..</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  <div class="splashAnimation" style="height:100%;display:flex;align-items:center;justify-content:center">
    <img style="width:100px;height:100px" src="http://brandmark.io/logo-rank/random/beats.png">
  </div>
  

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems OK to me, just make sure to remove the comments from your CSS (or use `/*` and `*/`. Note that `//` is not a valid comment in CSS.

```css
.demo {
  background:url('https://source.unsplash.com/random');
  background-size:cover;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
}

.splashAnimation{
  animation-name: rotateLogo;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@keyframes rotateLogo {
  0% {
    transform: rotateY(0deg)
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateY(360deg)
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="splashAnimation demo"></div>
```

Comment: if it's seems ok, better add comment ... or flag as `a problem that can no longer be reproduced`

Comment: its not okay though : /, animation goes the other direction many of the times

Comment: @GeorgeAvgoustis Please explain that. The "direction" completely depends on how your brain see it. It's just shrinking and then growing again, with no real rotating "direction".

Comment: i added a gif to illustrate

Comment: @GeorgeAvgoustis that's exactly the same as his answer. (for me both of them look to go other direction sometimes, that's just our brain)

Comment: Which is completely good, except your brain thinking it's not. You really should read that spinning dancer article on wikipedia.

Answer (score 0):

Two things to mention here.

### The issue

As people have mentioned due to the lack of visual cues, even though everything works fine on the software level, the wetware level(the brain) cannot understand what direction the icon is turning

### Potential solution

A solution to that is to add `perspective` to your transform which will distort your logo a bit but will provide enough information to your brain to perceive the rotation properly. The amount of perspective is a per case thing, in my case 150px worked. Remember, the lower the perspective value, the more intense the effect.

Answer (score -1):

You can use like this:

```
[see here]
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ua50q2jh/2/

Comment: That issn't rotating over the y-axis