# Rotate element of "Y" direction when it was previously rotated

Tags: jquery, css, animation, rotation, transform

I rotate the square like in this post:
[Rotating in the Y direction css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49626790/rotating-in-the-y-direction-css)
But i would like rotate them 45deg before on Z direction. Unfortunately after this Y directions change and my element rotate not exactly i want. I don`t know how exacly i can explain this but i include the image.

I try to manipulate with rotations but i really don`t know how i can handle with it. I try to use transform-origin also but it did not help.

I belive that image help to better explain.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzslO.png

Thank you for help in advance.